# Correct way to return list of fibonacci sequence using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I understand how to return a Fibonacci sequence using the iterative approach,
as well as the dynamic programming approach.

With recursion, I understand the recursion tree for Fibonacci.
and how to return Nth Fibonacci number

```
def fib(num):
    if num <= 2: 
        return num 

    return fib(num -1) + fib(num-2)

print(fib(5))
```

The above code returns `8` which is great,
but I want to understand how could I return a list of the sequence
by updating the above recursive code.

```
eg: [1,1,2,3,5,8]
```

Comment: Can you think of a rule that tells you what the list should be, in the cases where `num <= 2`? If you have a list of the first `num` Fibonacci numbers, can you think of code that would create a *new* list of the first `num+1` Fibonacci numbers and return it?

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence starts as 1, 1, 2, so your implementation will never produce the first 1 in the sequence.  I believe fib(1) and fib(2) are normally both 1, and fib(0) is therefore 0.  It's probably easiest to use fib(0) = 0 and fib(1) = 1, after which you can use recursion.  So to fix it, just change `<= 2` to `<= 1`.  To return a list, just create a wrapper function.  But note that without memoization, your recursive implementation is exponentially slow, i.e. it's the worst possible implementation.

Comment: i could say arr = [ -1 ] * num  then arr[0] = 0; arr[1] = 1. and then recursively call are[num]=fib(num-1) + fib(num-2) problem with that is I will have to declare arr=[] outside the function, is there a way to have that inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a Fibonacci sequence that begins with 0, we can rewrite your code recursively, without any external data, by doing:

```
def fib(index):
    if index <= 2:
        return [0, 1][:index]

    sequence = fib(index - 1)

    sequence.append(sum(sequence[-2:]))

    return sequence

print(fib(11))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
>
```

But as @TomKarzes comments, there are much better algorithms.  But since you insist on doing this recursively, efficiency isn't a primary concern.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    def fib(n):
        if n < 0: return []
        if n == 1: return [1]
        if n == 2: return [1,1]
    
        prevArray = fib(n-1)
        # returning a new array where the last element is the sum of the last 2 elements in the previous array
        return prevArray + [ prevArray[-1]+prevArray[-2] ]
```